# Как получить все комбинации расстановки N символов?

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо получить все возможные комбинации расстановки + и - для заданной длины, например для 2 это будет ++, --, +-, -+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С такой задачей отлично справляется [`itertools.cobinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Чтобы не терялись зеркальные комбинации `'+-', '-+'` передаем двойную строку `'+-+-'`, а для того чтобы комбинации не повторялись используем [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```
from itertools import combinations
print(set(combinations('+-'*2, 2)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, я правильно понял, что бы получить комбинации для трех символов - строку тоже надо тройную, для 4 четверную и т.д.?

Comment: @Sergey да, для N символ это выглядит так: `print(set(combinations('+-'*n, n)))`

Answer (score 3):

Если `+-` и `-+` различаются в вашем случае, то вам не комбинации ([сочетания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) нужны (которые порядок не учитывают), а [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) ([размещение с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(*map(''.join, itertools.combinations('+-', r=2)))
+-
>>> print(*map(''.join, itertools.combinations_with_replacement('+-', r=2)))
++ +- --
>>> print(*map(''.join, itertools.product('+-', repeat=2)))
++ +- -+ --
```

Answer (score 2):

Заметьте, что каждая такая расстановка соответствует бинарной записи некоторого числа, только вместо `0` пишется `-`, а вместо единицы - плюс.

Отсюда простой способ генерации - перечислить в цикле все числа от `0` до `2^N-1`, выводя их бинарное представление с использованием алфавита `"-+"`

```
 N = 4
 for k in range(1<<N):
      print(''.join('+' if (1 & (k >> i)) else '-' for i in range(N)))
```

Если строки перевернуть `[::-1]`, порядок будет лексикографический

Comment: `for n in range(2**N): print(f'{n:0{N}b}'.translate(dict(zip(map(ord, "10"), "+-"))))`

Comment: @jfs `f'{n:0{N}b}'` как интерпретировать?

Comment: [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings): отформатировать `n` в двоичной системе, дополняя слева до `N` цифр нулями, если необходимо.

Comment: @jfs О, спасибо. IMHO, это всё же трудно читается без опыта.

Comment: из сложного здесь то, что `{N}` вложено внутрь `{n}`. А так язык для `str.format` полезно знать, если на Питоне программируете.